# equation related to lagrange error formula.

Tags: integration, taylor-expansion, error-function

So im trying to show that $E_2(x)$ =  $\int_{a}^{x} \frac{f'''(t)(x-t)^2}{2}dt$. In the problem they want this to be done by using the equation

$E_2(x)$ = $E_1(x)$ - $\frac{f''(a)(x-a)^2}{2}$

where we know

$E_1(x) =  \int_{a}^{x} f''(t)(x-t)dt$

my attempt to solve it:

want to show that $E_2(x)$ =  $\int_{a}^{x} \frac{f'''(t)(x-t)^2}{2}dt$.

We have:

$E_2(x)$ = $E_1(x)$ - $\frac{f''(a)(x-a)^2}{2}$

$E_1(x) =  \int_{a}^{x} f''(t)(x-t)dt$

$E_2(x)$ = $\int_{a}^{x} f''(t)(x-t)dt$ - $\frac{f''(a)(x-a)^2}{2}$

doing integration by parts differentiating $f''(t)$, and integrating $(x-t)$ we get:

$E_2(x)$ = $ \tfrac{f''(t)(x-t)^2}{2}\Big|_a^x -  \int_{a}^{x} \frac{f'''(t)(x-t)^2}{2}dt$ - $\frac{f''(a)(x-a)^2}{2}$

$E_2(x) = $  -  $\int_{a}^{x} \frac{f'''(t)(x-t)^2}{2}dt$ - ${f''(a)(x-a)^2}$

However at that point i dont see how i should progress. thanks in advance